# Two Strings not Equal when Compared although they are the same

Tags: string, excel, vba

Hey guys/gals, having some trouble in VB, I am reading in a string from Excel and comparing it to another, when I see the MSGBox they look identical, yet VB is not recognizing them as the same and its been screwing me up thanks.

```
    Sub runit()
 Dim indicator As Integer
 Dim actual As String
  Dim tmp As String
 tmp = "3. AIRCRAF"
     Sheets("Sheet2").Select
For i = 3 To 1200

actual = Left(Cells(i, 1).Text, 10)
If i = 203 Then
MsgBox actual & tmp
End If

If actual = tmp Then
MsgBox i
Cells(i, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:M997").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
tmp = "zzZZxxXXedc"

End If

Next
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
tmp = "H."
indicator = 0


For j = 1 To 600

If tmp = actual Then
indicator = 1
Cells(j, 1).Select
    tmp = "zzZZxxXXedc"
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:M1200").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    End If

    Next
If indicator = 0 Then
    actual = Left(Cells(j, 1).Value, 2)
    Rows(j + 1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working.  Still don't know what was wrong.  Figured if I used Mid on both the variables maybe it'd work and it did. Just thought maybe someone could explain why.

```
    Sub runit()
 Dim indicator As Integer
 Dim actual As String
  Dim tmp As String

 tmp = Mid("3. AIRCRAFT STATUS", 1, 10)
     Sheets("Sheet2").Select
For i = 3 To 1200

actual = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Text, 1, 10)
If i = 203 Then
MsgBox (actual) & " " & (tmp)
End If

If actual = tmp Then
MsgBox i
Cells(i, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:M997").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
tmp = "zzZZxxXXedc"

End If

Next
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
tmp = Mid("H. MAJOR INSP REQUIREMENTS:", 1, 5)
indicator = 0


For j = 1 To 600

If tmp = actual Then
indicator = 1
Cells(j, 1).Select
    tmp = "zzZZxxXXedc"
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:M1200").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    End If

    Next
If indicator = 0 Then
    actual = Mid(Cells(j, 1).Text, 1, 5)
    Rows(j + 1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the more nasty cases, visual inspection is not sufficient to identify the culprit that screws up a comparison. (Sequences of) whitespace or similar glyphys for different unicode codepoints may fool the eye. So invest in a function that takes a string and returns its 'hexdump' (using Hex, AscW, Mid, and padding) and apply that to LookFor (renamed from your tmp, which is riskily reused) and to actual.